# Why is my Object in my NSXMLParser not retaining the previous values?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsxmlparser

I am working on parsing a big xml and storing it into a temporary core data table. My parser didEndElement method looks as follows:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"reference_number"]) {
        [[self pdfDocument] setEducationDocumentReference:currentTextString];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        [[self pdfDocument] setEducationDocumentName:currentTextString];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"type"]) {
        [[self pdfDocument] setEducationDocumentType:currentTextString];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"date"]) {
        [[self pdfDocument] setEducationDocumentDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:currentTextString]];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"url"]) {
        [[self pdfDocument] setEducationDocumentURL:currentTextString];

        //If I uncomment the following, the app will try finding the previous set
        //values without any luck and crash.
        //if (![pdfDocument documentExistsInTemporaryTable]) {
        //  [pdfDocument saveDocumentToTemporaryTable];
        //}
    }
}
```

It clearly separates every value as it should be and it should be storing it into the pdfDocument object before saving the object to the temp table, but when I try to access any previously set values for the pdfDocument I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS which from what I can see is because it is not finding the value for the previous pdfDocument variables.

I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake, but can someone enlighten me towards the right direction here?

Comment: Your problem lies in other parts of the code... You need to post the code for `documentExistsInTemporaryTable` where your program crashed! How did you expect us to find your bug **without seeing the very code which crashed your program??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem laid on using the same pointer to the same object. The solution I chose was to have different instances for each value, by simply copying the currentTextString.